# How to align several lists using the enumerate environment?

Tags: margins, enumerate, indentation, labels, enumitem

I'd like to align the left margin of these lists. This is what I get:

[image] [image]

This is what I want:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
 \quad \newline
 This is a list of items:
 \begin{enumerate}[labelindent=1.5em, labelsep=3.8mm, leftmargin=*, label=SV\arabic*]
  \item First item
  \item Second item
  \item Third item
 \end{enumerate}
 This is another list of items:
 \begin{enumerate}[labelindent=1.5em, labelsep=3.8mm, leftmargin=*, label=N\arabic*]
  \item First item
  \item Second item
 \end{enumerate}
 One more list of items:
 \begin{enumerate}[labelindent=1.5em, labelsep=3.8mm, leftmargin=*, label=(\roman*)]
  \item First item
  \item Second item
  \item Third item
 \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used `leftmargin` and set it to specific value rather than `*`, then `labelindent` will be irrelevant. To align the text of different lists together use `leftmargin=<value>`.

If you want to get global settings for lists, use `\setlist[enumerate,1]{<specs you want>}`. For `leftmargin`, set it to `\widthof{\hspace{\parindent}SV}`. This will help you get more visually pleasing result because the lists will not exceed the normal margin in your document. Here, `\widthof` takes an argument and calculates its width, and by setting the argument to `hspace{\parindent}SV` we will automatically add the normal paragraph indentation + the width of the text `SV` (which belongs to the largest item label in the work shown above).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlength{\enuleftmarginl}
\setlength{\enuleftmarginl}{\widthof{\hspace{\parindent}SV}}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{labelsep=3.8mm, leftmargin=\enuleftmarginl, label=\arabic*.}


\begin{document}
\quad \newline
This is a list of items:
    \begin{enumerate}[label=SV\arabic*]
        \item First item
        \item Second item
        \item Third item
    \end{enumerate}
This is another list of items:
    \begin{enumerate}[label=N\arabic*]
        \item First item
        \item Second item
    \end{enumerate}
One more list of items:
    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
        \item First item
        \item Second item
        \item Third item
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

See in the result below how the list label is align almost with the text and how entries of all lists are aligned together.

[image]

if you want to get more precise label alignment for the second list, use `[leftmargin=\widthof{\hspace{\parindent}N}, label=N\arabic*]` as an optional argument for its `enumerate` environment, which gives you

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You were quite close but just didn't set the `leftmargin`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\quad \newline
 This is a list of items:
 \begin{enumerate}[labelindent=1.5em, labelsep=3.8mm, leftmargin=15mm, label=SV\arabic*]
  \item First item
  \item Second item
  \item Third item
 \end{enumerate}
 This is another list of items:
 \begin{enumerate}[labelindent=1.5em, labelsep=3.8mm, leftmargin=15mm, label=N\arabic*]
  \item First item
  \item Second item
 \end{enumerate}
 One more list of items:
 \begin{enumerate}[labelindent=1.5em, labelsep=3.8mm, leftmargin=15mm, label=(\roman*)]
  \item First item
  \item Second item
  \item Third item
 \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can set up a new list type and then don't need to type all values every time.

Comment: Wow, thanks. Sigur could you tell me how can I do that? It would be really useful.